# I can't found my mistake in my simple C-loop,the printf doesnt work

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, floating-point, printf

Down there is my code,when i try to compile it the printf doesnt work,what do you think?Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    float i;
    for(i=0.0f; i < 1.0f; i+=0.05f){
        if(i == 0.5f)
            printf("Die Hälfte ist erreicht\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never compare floating point values with `==` or `!=`. You might not get the exact value you are testing for. The internal representation of the values might not be exactly `0.5` but something like `0.499999765` or `0.500000123`.

Comment: So,what do you think I should do in this example,to make it works?THANK YOU!

Comment: You have to add some more details. First of all, what is exactly the error message you get? Also add information about how exactly you compile it, what is the compiler you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating-point arithmetic is designed to approximate real-number arithmetic. The `0.05f` in source code is converted from that decimal numeral to a binary format that approximates it. Further, each time `i += 0.05f` is executed, the real-number sum is rounded to fit in the `float` format. The rounding errors that causes may either compound or cancel, moving the current value of `i` further from or nearer to what you would have if real-number arithmetic were used.

To iterate with an arithmetic sequence of floating-point values, you can use integer values for a counter and then scale the counter as desired:

```
for (float iteration = 0; iteration < 20; iteration += 1)
{
    float i = iteration / 20;
    if (i == 0.5f)
        printf("Die Hälfte ist erreicht\n");
}
```

However, there may be additional subtleties involved in any code more complicated than this, so it is necessary to learn about floating-point arithmetic in order to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are based on binary numbers. It may not be possible to exactly represent the value of a decimal number but only a value that is very close.

That means you should avoid comparisons `==` or `!=` for floating point numbers.

One option is to convert your program to count using integer numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    float f;
    for(int i=0; i < 100; i+=5){
        if(i == 50)
            printf("Die Hälfte ist erreicht\n");
        f = (float)i / 100f;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another option is to compare the difference between floating point numbers with a small number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    float i;
    for(i=0.0f; i < 1.0f; i+=0.05f){
        float diff = i - 0.5f;
        if(diff < 0) diff = (-diff);
        if(diff < 0.01)
            printf("Die Hälfte ist erreicht\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```